# Trabalhando com multiplos selects em form group

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho dois selects:

```
<div class="select">
  <select [class.disabled]="loadingcadastro" (change)="getIdTipoVariacao(item.value.tipo, i)" formControlName="tipo" class="select-text">
    <option class="dropdown-item" selected>{{item.value.tipo || 'Tipo da Variação'}}</option>
    <option [hidden]="item.value.tipo == tipoVariacao.valor" *ngFor="let tipoVariacao of tiposvariacoes;let j = index"
      class="dropdown-item">{{tipoVariacao.valor}}</option>
  </select>


  <span class="select-highlight"></span>
  <span class="select-bar"></span>
</div>
```

```
<div class="select">
  <select formControlName="valor_atributo" class="select-text">
    <option class="dropdown-item" selected>{{item.value.valor || 'Valor'}}</option>
    <option *ngFor="let ValorAtributo of listaAtributos;let x = index"
      class="dropdown-item">{{ValorAtributo.valor}}</option>
  </select>


  <span class="select-highlight"></span>
  <span class="select-bar"></span>
</div>
```

Conforme a escolha do primeiro select, é enviado para a função getIdTipoVariacao o nome daquela variação e o indice.
Através desses dados eu consigo enviar para o meu backend o id da primeira option selecionada para que me retorne os dados do segundo select.

O problema acontece que se eu tiver dois selects na tela, quando eu altero o primeiro select, os outros selects subsequentes recebem o valor "Valor". No caso apenas o primeiro select deveria receber o valor "Valor":

Segue meu ts:

```
getIdTipoVariacao(variacao:string, index: number) { // pega o id de um determinado tipo de variação para mandar para a função get-lista-valor-atributo para obter a lista de atributos daquela variação
    for(let i=0;i<this.tiposvariacoes.length;i++){
      if(this.tiposvariacoes[i].valor == variacao){
        this.idTipoVariacao = this.tiposvariacoes[i].id
      }
    }

    //Tendo o id selecionado, já pode copular a próxima combobox de valores:
    this.listaValoresAtributo(this.idTipoVariacao);

        //Condição criada pois ao selecionar um Tipo de Variação, selecionar um atributo e depois trocar o tipo de variação, o atributo selecionado continuava na lista de tipo de variações.
    //Agora quando já existe um atributo selecionado e é trocado para outro tipo de variação que não contempla aquele atributo, é voltado para o valor padrão.
    if(this.variacaoForm.value.variacoes[index].valor != null){
      this.variacaoForm.value.variacoes[index].valor = null;
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de quando alterasse a opção do primeiro select, alterasse para a opção padrao "Valor", mas apenas do primeiro sellect.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Acredito que por estar disparando um evento `change()` qualquer alteração de valor que esteja no seu primeiro select realmente ocasionará o disparo do seu método `getIdTipoVariacao()`, você quer que isso ocorra quando o usuário selecionar a primeira vez mas em seguida o valor padrão do primeiro retorne, isso?

Comment: Tipo, tem quatro selects. uma depende da escolha da outra. Se na primeira eu selecionei "Cor", a segunda select gera as options "Azul, verde, amarelo".

No meu próximo select eu seleciono "Tamanho", a segunda select gera as options "P, M, G", o problema é que depois de escolher esses dois, se eu resolver trocar o tamanho para cor, ambos meus selects recebem "Valor"

Comment: editei o post adicionando uma print